Unable to handle websocket event laravel reverb
Reverb Version
1.0.0
Laravel Version
11.10.0
PHP Version
8.3.6
Description
I am experiencing an issue with connecting to Laravel Reverb in my Laravel application. Despite following the setup instructions provided in the Laravel Reverb documentation, I am unable to establish a connection
Setup 1
mydomain.conf
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/html/mydomain/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /app/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_ssl_name $host;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;

        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
    }

    location /apps/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_ssl_name $host;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;

        keepalive_timeout 300s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_send_timeout 300s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
    }


    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    }
    server {
        if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
        if ($host = mydomain.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }

config/reverb.php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Reverb Server
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default server used by Reverb to handle
    | incoming messages as well as broadcasting message to all your
    | connected clients. At this time only "reverb" is supported.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('REVERB_SERVER', 'reverb'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Reverb Servers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define details for each of the supported Reverb servers.
    | Each server has its own configuration options that are defined in
    | the array below. You should ensure all the options are present.
    |
    */

    'servers' => [

        'reverb' => [
            'host' => env('REVERB_SERVER_HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
            'port' => env('REVERB_SERVER_PORT', 8080),
            'hostname' => env('REVERB_HOST'),
            'options' => [
                'tls' => [

                ],
            ],
            'max_request_size' => env('REVERB_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE', 10_000),
            'scaling' => [
                'enabled' => env('REVERB_SCALING_ENABLED', false),
                'channel' => env('REVERB_SCALING_CHANNEL', 'reverb'),
                'server' => [
                    'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
                    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
                    'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
                    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
                    'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
                ],
            ],
            'pulse_ingest_interval' => env('REVERB_PULSE_INGEST_INTERVAL', 15),
            'telescope_ingest_interval' => env('REVERB_TELESCOPE_INGEST_INTERVAL', 15),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Reverb Applications
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define how Reverb applications are managed. If you choose
    | to use the "config" provider, you may define an array of apps which
    | your server will support, including their connection credentials.
    |
    */

    'apps' => [

        'provider' => 'config',

        'apps' => [
            [
                'key' => env('REVERB_APP_KEY'),
                'secret' => env('REVERB_APP_SECRET'),
                'app_id' => env('REVERB_APP_ID'),
                'options' => [
                    'host' => env('REVERB_HOST'),
                    'port' => env('REVERB_PORT', 443),
                    'scheme' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https'),
                    'useTLS' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',

                ],
                'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
                'ping_interval' => env('REVERB_APP_PING_INTERVAL', 60),
                'max_message_size' => env('REVERB_APP_MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE', 10_000),
            ],
        ],

    ],

];


.env
BROADCAST_DRIVER=reverb
REVERB_APP_ID=1234567
REVERB_APP_KEY=abcdefghijkl
REVERB_APP_SECRET=abcdefghijkl
REVERB_HOST=mydomain.com
REVERB_PORT=443
REVERB_SCHEME=https

VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY="${REVERB_APP_KEY}"
VITE_REVERB_HOST="mydomain.com"
VITE_REVERB_PORT=443
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME=https

now i can connect with wss://

but when i trigger Event i'm getting this error

when i trigger post request of https://yugmedeals.com/apps/292267/events? without port (8080) using postman i'm getting 500 - Internal Server Error
in laravel.log -- [2024-07-20 15:47:03] local.ERROR: syntax error
Setup 2
config/reverb.php
'tls' => [
                    'local_cert' => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem',
                    'local_pk' => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem',
                ],

Now I'm unable to connect with wss:// itself
help me to resolve this issue

Sry wrong reply
